# how to do this compute the matrix of $<,>$ with respect to the basis $B=\{1,x,x^2\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = \mathbb{R}[x]_{\le2}$ be the $\mathbb{R}-$vector space of polynomials
$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$ with real coefficients $a_i$ in $\mathbb{R}$, of degree $\le2$.

Define,
$$\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle =\int_{-2}^{2}f(x)g(x)dx$$

Compute the matrix of $\langle .,.\rangle$ with respect to the basis $B = \{1, x, x^2\}$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Define the variables $$\mathbf a = (a_0,a_1,a_2)^T, \mathbf b = (b_0,b_1,b_2)^T, \text{ and } P = \begin{pmatrix}p_{00} & p_{01} & p_{02} \\ p_{10} & p_{11} & p_{12} \\ p_{20} & p_{21} & p_{22} \end{pmatrix}$$ Also, let $$f(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 \text{ and } g(x) = b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2$$

Then, $P$ is a matrix for $\langle\cdot , \cdot\rangle$ iff

$$ \mathbf a^T P \mathbf b = \langle f(x), g(x)\rangle = \int_{-2}^2 f(x)g(x)\text dx$$

Evaluating the left-hand side gives

$$ \mathbf a^T P \mathbf b = \sum\limits_{i=0}^2\sum\limits_{j=0}^2 p_{ij}a_ib_j$$

so the $ij$-th entry of $P$ is the coefficient of $a_ib_j$. Evaluating the right-hand side gives

$$ \int_{-2}^2 f(x)g(x)\text dx = \int_{-2}^2 (a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2)(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2)\text dx \\ = 4a_0b_0 + \frac{16}{3}a_0b_2 + \frac{16}{3}a_1b_1 + \frac{16}{3}a_2b_0 + \frac{64}{5}a_2b_2$$

Putting this information together, we can deduce the entries of the matrix $P$:

$$ P = \begin{pmatrix}4 & 0 & \frac{16}{3} \\ 0 & \frac{16}{3} & 0 \\ \frac{16}{3} & 0 & \frac{64}{5} \end{pmatrix} $$